# How to set up flat network in openstack?

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron

I deployed openstack via openstack-ansible and I'm trying to set up an openstack network so that the instances are accessible from the physical network (192.168.10.0/20):

```
openstack network create --share --external \
--provider-physical-network flat \
--provider-network-type flat public

openstack subnet create --network public \
--allocation-pool start=192.168.14.241,end=192.168.14.249 \
--dns-nameserver 192.168.10.144 --gateway 192.168.10.1 \
--subnet-range 192.168.10.0/20 public-subnet
```

but instances do not receive ip addresses and do not ping anything.

This is my ml2_conf.ini:

```
cat /etc/neutron/plugins/ml2/ml2_conf.ini
[ml2]
type_drivers = flat,vlan,vxlan,local
tenant_network_types = vxlan,flat,vlan
mechanism_drivers = linuxbridge
extension_drivers = port_security
# ML2 flat networks

[ml2_type_flat]
flat_networks = flat
# ML2 VLAN networks

[ml2_type_vlan]
network_vlan_ranges = vlan:101:200,vlan:301:400
# ML2 VXLAN networks

[ml2_type_vxlan]
vxlan_group = 239.1.1.1
vni_ranges = 1:1000

[ml2_type_geneve]
vni_ranges =
max_header_size = 38
# Security groups

[securitygroup]
enable_security_group = True
enable_ipset = True
```

Have any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Does your flat network serve DHCP? Usually, with flat networks you need to provide the ip configuration differently, e.g. via config-drive. So it may not be your neutron config but just a missing step to configure the instance's IPs and gateway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- 1, check whether the `network:dhcp` port exist or not, it should exist and show that there is one or more ports which has the `ip` at the head of the range within **`start=192.168.14.241,end=192.168.14.249`**. Like this:

```
# openstack port list --device-owner network:dhcp
+--------------------------------------+------+-------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
| ID                                   | Name | MAC Address       | Fixed IP Addresses                                                         | Status |
+--------------------------------------+------+-------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
| 08db769d-7500-41c0-bc3a-086fdb75c65d |      | fa:16:3e:4f:76:75 | ip_address='192.168.1.2', subnet_id='83e0dea2-cee3-437b-94c7-d5650d94d921' | ACTIVE |
+--------------------------------------+------+-------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
```

- 2, check there is generate the bridge correctly (brq**f775913d-8f** consist with the head of the **Network**'s ID, and there is some `tapXXX` for port which should attach to the instance), like this:

```
# openstack subnet list
+--------------------------------------+-----------+--------------------------------------+----------------+
| ID                                   | Name      | Network                              | Subnet         |
+--------------------------------------+-----------+--------------------------------------+----------------+
| 83e0dea2-cee3-437b-94c7-d5650d94d921 | flat_snet | f775913d-8f9d-4f46-9fe7-2a1bce710ec6 | 192.168.1.0/24 |
+--------------------------------------+-----------+--------------------------------------+----------------+

# brctl show
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
brqf775913d-8f      8000.000ec6ade4f2   no      enx000ec6ade4f2
                            tap08db769d-75
                            tapd4d2a5e3-fd
docker0     8000.0242e6da798c   no
```

- 3, check the instance has configured with the correct ip info (`ip a` and `ip r s` or others to check the network traffic like `traceroute`) by login the instance console.
- 4, in my situation, we should set the `pvid`'s value as the only one `flat` network's `vlanID` in the switch ports which connect to the hypervisors, because we have other `vlan` networks which configured as `vlan` type in openstack cluster.

Comment: VictorLee, thanks for your answer!  
It really helped, here's what I did:  
1) Enabled DHCP in the subnet settings (while the allocation-pool left the same)
2) Added a physical network interface to the bridge with a name like the network id

Comment: @AlexG My pleasure, but one thing I can't understand why should you add a physical network interface by manual? In my practical, it would auto generate the `brctl show`'s result while I configure with `network_interface: "enp3s0";neutron_external_interface: "enx000ec6ade4f2"` in **/etc/kolla/globals.yml**. Could you **restart `neutron-server`** (use caution) and generate the new interfaces automatically? Or maybe you need to add the interfaces by manual after the service or hypervisor reboot.